# how do I xPath to a value in a select statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath, xquery

XML is in a column in a table. I want to select this specific value:

```
<CreditDebitAdjustments xmlns="http://....">
  <CreditDebitAdjustment>
    <Header>
      <CreditDebitAdjustmentHeader>
        <Amount>-111.58</Amount>
```

Here's what I tried to do:

```
SELECT 
   *, 
   XMLPayload.query('/CreditDebitAdjustments/CreditDebitAdjustment/Header/CreditDebitAdjustmentHeader/Amount') AS Amount 
FROM Table
WHERE CustomerID = 8
```

How do I go about extracting the value -111.58?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **respect** the XML namespace that's defined on your XML!

```
<CreditDebitAdjustments xmlns="http://....">
                         ********************
```

Include this in your query and you should be fine:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://.......')
  SELECT 
      XMLPayload.value('(/CreditDebitAdjustments/CreditDebitAdjustment/Header/CreditDebitAdjustmentHeader/Amount)[1]', 'decimal(20,2)') AS Amount 
  FROM Table
  WHERE CustomerID = 8
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`value()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) method and define your [XML Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx):

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://.......')
SELECT XMLPayload.value('/CreditDebitAdjustments[1]/CreditDebitAdjustment[1]/Header[1]/CreditDebitAdjustmentHeader[1]/Amount[1]', 'decimal(10, 4)') AS Amount
FROM Table
WHERE CustomerID = 8;
```

since the `value()` method requires a singleton you can only get the nth occurrence from each node (1st from each in the above example). If you need to get all occurrences you will need to use this in conjunction with [`nodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx):

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://.......')
SELECT X.value('Amount[1]', 'decimal(10, 4)') AS Amount
FROM Table AS t
CROSS APPLY XMLPayload.nodes('/CreditDebitAdjustments/CreditDebitAdjustment/Header/CreditDebitAdjustmentHeader') AS n (X)
WHERE CustomerID = 8;
```

Simple Example:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (XMLPayload XML)
INSERT @T
VALUES ('<CreditDebitAdjustments>
  <CreditDebitAdjustment>
    <Header>
      <CreditDebitAdjustmentHeader>
        <Amount>-111.58</Amount>
      </CreditDebitAdjustmentHeader>
      <CreditDebitAdjustmentHeader>
        <Amount>5</Amount>
      </CreditDebitAdjustmentHeader>
    </Header>
  </CreditDebitAdjustment>
    </CreditDebitAdjustments>');

SELECT XMLPayload.value('/CreditDebitAdjustments[1]/CreditDebitAdjustment[1]/Header[1]/CreditDebitAdjustmentHeader[1]/Amount[1]', 'decimal(10, 4)') AS Amount
FROM @T;

SELECT X.value('Amount[1]', 'decimal(10, 4)') AS Amount
FROM @T AS t
CROSS APPLY XMLPayload.nodes('/CreditDebitAdjustments/CreditDebitAdjustment/Header/CreditDebitAdjustmentHeader') AS n (X);
```